# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in sql on different dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, between

I have a simple question:

```
select cast( '11-04-15' as date)
```

works in SQL, but

```
select cast( '14-04-15' as date)
```

throws an error

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string
```

Why does it happen?
Dates above 12 throw the error.

Comment: you probably have a system default off mm-dd-yyyy, there's only 12 months =p

Comment: try this instead `CAST ('20150414' AS DATE)`

Comment: Best option is to *not* use strings at all but store dates using a date-type and use date-typed parameters and variables.

Answer (score 2):

> yes, it's logical that it'll throw an exception. the cause is you need
>   to maintain a specific date format like `dd-mm-yyyy` or `mm-dd-yy` or
>   something else

you can set the date format yourself using `DATEFORMATSET DATEFORMAT { format | @format_var }` 
default is `mdy` and Valid parameters are `mdy, dmy, ymd, ydm, myd, and dym`

see [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) for more clarification.

when you are trying `select cast( '11-04-15' as date)`, it's accept `11` as a `month` and `04` as a `date`, which is valid because default date format id `mm-dd-yyyy`

but in `select cast( '14-04-15' as date)` this it's accept `14` as a `month` which is invalid for the default date format, so you need to change it using `set dateformat your_specific_date_format`.

try

```
set dateformat dmy

select cast('11-04-15' as date)
select cast( '14-04-15' as date)
```

both will work,because current date format is `dd-mm-yyy`

`11` and `14` both treat as a day which's valid for a date.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SET DATEFORMAT` to set the date format to DDMMYY. Something like this.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

SELECT CAST( '11-04-15' as date);
SELECT CAST( '14-04-15' as date);
```

you can also use `CONVERT`

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'11-04-15',3);
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'14-04-15',3);
```

or YYYYMMDD format to input the date string as suggested by Giorgos Betsos

```
SELECT CAST ('20150414' AS DATE)
```

Comment: You can't always know the `DATEFORMAT` of the input data, nor should you have to. The same goes for using `CONVERT`. Best option is to use `date`-typed data *only*. Date literals should use the unseparated date format, as it's the only unambiguous format